# Umbraco get element sub child - trigger pop up

Tags: umbraco

Quite a tough one to tackle here.

Here is my tree structure:

[image]

Currently, if you are to visit the "Community Celebrations" page you will see all "Celebrations" listed on this page.

Here is what the page spits out: [image]

To identify which node is a "Celebration" look at the icon that "Banswara" is using - this is a "Celebration".

Underneath you will see nodes named Stat, Community Video, Touching Story and Photo.

What I am trying to achieve ( and am unsure if it is possible ) is on the "Community Celebrations" page ( see image above ) where all celebrations are listed I want to be able to render the video that you see at the bottom. How a user inputs this video is through the umbraco RTE within the "Community Video" node. The user will insert YouTube "object" embedded code but there is a catch. To pull this through is no problem, if a user is to click on the play icon or in video space I need a pop up to trigger which will contain the video.

I am using fancybox for current jquery pop ups and to be able to do so within umbraco you need a dedicated template with the content you want to render within - my thinking is that this cannot be done as the video content is coming from another node with a dedicated template however, there maybe someone with an alternative option.

Big post I know but this is a tough one!

All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to here for solution to this question:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/33536-Umbraco-get-element-sub-child-trigger-pop-up